# how to collect data from json objects with multiple keys and push all values to single key:value array

Tags: javascript, json, object, ecmascript-6, foreach

I have a sample json object:

```
var jsonString = '[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":Mercedes},{ "name":"Jimy", "age":32, "car":Audi},{ 
"name":"Mia", "age":22, "car":Renault},{ "name":"Frank", "age":35, "car":null }]';

var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

I would like to grab latest two data from the data array and create a single key:value array so that for each json property there is a key in the array, and all the values from all the json objects are stored under their appropriate key, so for example, the result I Would like to have is generically array [{key: data_array_for_that_key}] or specifically:

```
output=[{name: [Frank, Mia]}, {age: [35,22]}, {car: [null, Renault]}......]
```

I've tried something like this:

```
var output = [];

  data.slice(-2).forEach((d, i) => {
    Object.keys(d).forEach((key) => {
      output.push({[key] : d[key]});
    });
  });
  console.log(output);
```

but it creates a key and value for each json object which is not what I want.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coult take a hash table for groupung same keys and push for each new key a new object to `output`;

```js
var jsonString = '[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "car":"Mercedes"},{ "name":"Jimy", "age":32, "car":"Audi"},{"name": "Mia", "age": 22, "car": "Renault"},{"name": "Frank","age": 35,"car": null}]',
    data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    output = [],
    temp = [];

data.slice(-2).forEach(o => Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (!temp[k]) output.push({ [k]: temp[k] = [] });
    temp[k].push(v);
}));

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```